# Swift UITableView scrollToRow not working

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with multiple lines and textFields. Some of the textFields won't be visible when the keyboard is visible. So I want the selected row to scroll to top to be visible.
I'm using

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
tableViewActivity.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

for this to scroll the selected row to top. This code is inside `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and is called correctly, but the tableView does nothing, there is no scroll. I found a post with a workaround for some by using a delay or reload the Data before scrolling, but nothing changed for me with this. So can anybody help me please?

Comment: what is the value of 'index'

Comment: Have you tried change the tableView insets after keyboards open?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS UITableView contentOffset when keyboard is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873674/ios-uitableview-contentoffset-when-keyboard-is-shown)